# Mongoose check if text exist in any of Map entry value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We need to put translation in Map within a JSON object. When we search for an item, we will only pass the name and we need to check if that name is in one of the translation object.

Example:

```
"item" : {
  "name" : {
     "en_US": "Hello"
     "id_ID" : "Halo"
  }
}
```

The client will only send the `name` but we won't know the language used (e.g, *Halo*) and we need to return the document with that `name` in any language. How should   we define the filter object? So far all the example I saw require that the we define the complete object info to filter (ex: `item.name.id_ID`).

Answer (score 1):

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NPVmIU203ys)

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {//reshape it to match on value field
      "field": {
        "$objectToArray": "$item.name"
      }
    }
  },
  {//reshape again to get the only matching element
    "$unwind": "$field"
  },
  {
    $match: {//match condition
      "field.v": "Hello"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {//project only what is needed
      "field.k": 1,
      "item": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I use it in Mongoose `find` and `paginate` method?

Comment: I would suggest you to try it out and post an update. So that anyone can help. I have not much idea about mongoose. Let me check.